# How to generate a tree hash of a git sparse checkout?

Tags: git, sparse-checkout

You can get the hash of a tree in a commit by doing:

```
git rev-parse 'HEAD^{tree}'
```

And you can get the hash of the tree in the index by doing:

```
git write-tree
```

However, in the case you did a sparse checkout by doing

```
git sparse-checkout init
git sparse-checkout set toto
```

Then running `git write-tree` will still print the hash of the full tree, *including* the files hidden by the sparse checkout. You can verify that by running `git cat-file -p $(git write-tree)`, which will print all the files and directories at the top level.

How to generate the hash of a tree that includes only the files checked out by a sparse checkout?

Answer (score 1):

I found one trick that works, although I don't know what the performance would look like in big repositories: you can `git rm` all the paths from the index, before doing `git add` with only the paths that are checked out.

```
# Remove all files, including the ones not checked out
git rm -r --sparse --cached --quiet .
# Re-add all checked-out files
git add -u
# Then run git write-tree to get a hash
git write-tree
```

Comment: I honestly think something like that is your only way, because git doesn't even *have* an internal tree object that's "cut down" to the sparse checkout until you create it, since it's *only* the checkout (i.e. the working directory) that's sparse and not anything else about the repo.